# What is TBD meaning in the specs of GPU?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, pc, vga

I know that the core speed of a VGA is a number, for example: 1365 MHz, 1500 MHz, 1530 MHz ; Some GPUs have core speed is TBD. So what does it mean? I have googled around but find nothing.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It stands for To Be Determined

Comment: But why? Why don't they have a range of number? How do I know the base clock is 1000MHz or 2000MHz?

Comment: I'm not sure why the chart doesn't have it, but the base clock is 1530MHz and boost is 1725MHz.  Source: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/graphics-cards/gtx-1650-super/

Comment: Or rather "To Be Disclosed"

Answer (score 0):

TBD -> "to be decided" or "to be determined".
Sometimes some electronics manufacturers release a datasheet for a product whose parameters have not yet been fully tested or measured. This is done to present a new product and get already potential customers. These datasheets will be completed in the future. You can check on the manufacturer's website, as there may already be a newer version of the document with completed parameters.